# Getting the names of members of an array in javascript dynamically at runtime

Tags: javascript, object, runtime, dynamically-generated, members

First of all I am not sure whether it is actually possible in javascript, but still I felt it's worth asking.

Ok, so what I am trying to do is get the names of the members of an array (or object as you might say) dynamically at runtime.

Let me explain. I have an object like this :

`Results :-`

`member_name1 : value_1`

`member_name2 : value_2`

`member_name3 : value_3`

Here, `Result` is the name of the object which has members like `member_name1`, `member_name2`, etc and theu have values like `value_1` and `value_2` respectively. What I am trying to do is get the name of the members like `member_name1` this at runtime; not it's value. I access the value by `Results.member_name1` generally.

I hope I am able to portray the issue!

Below is a screenshot of the object :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzAgm.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `obj` is your object, you can get the names of all its properties this way:

```
var names = [];

for(var name in obj) {
    names.push(name);
}
```

However, be aware that this will also pick up any extensions that have been made to `obj` through the `prototype` property of its class. If you want to exclude these and only get the properties defined on `obj` itself, you can filter them out with

```
for(var name in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        names.push(name);
    }
}
```

More information on `for...in` [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Answer (score 1):

You can access them using JavaScript *for* construct. Consider the following:

```
var member_names = [],
    data = {
        foo1: 'bar1',
        foo2: 'bar2',
        foo3: 'bar3',
    };

​for (var i in data) {
    member_names.push(i);
}

console.log(member_names);
```

​Here we have an empty array called *member_names* and your data object. In our loop, *i* will reference the property name, so you can push it onto the member_names array and then have access to them all there.